# Recommended Tomcat's Java Heap Size to Server HPSM9.41 webtier

Tags: java, tomcat, hp-service-manager

Our company uses `HP Service Manager 9.41` to manage ticketing, The web application(called webtier) is hosted in Apache Tomcat, the issue we are facing is running into performance issues with a high CPU load, I wonder if this could be related into `Java Heap Size` as the initial and the maximum memory pool is set into `1024MB` currently in a server with 12GB of RAM.

So my question is, is there in recommendations about the Value of the Java Heap Size?

Comment: You can check the GC activity by activating GC logging or with `jstat`, or another way, and then know if the CPU spikes are related to the GC. With 1G it's very likely undersized for a professional software.

Comment: @EugèneAdell I will enable GC logging and I will see the result Thanks

Comment: I augmented the max heap size into 4G and I enabled GC logging, it seems okay: `[GC [PSYoungGen: 1149244K->40510K(1124864K)] 2502875K->1421040K(2914304K), 0.0829119 secs] [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.08 secs]`

Comment: It seems OK but it needs further monitoring, particularly when the website is under heavy load (choose the peak time if you know it)

Comment: Thank you @EugèneAdell, as menstionned in the answer Service Manager works fine with a maximum heap size set into 2GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back to answer my question, may be others will face the same issue.

Thanks to @Eugène Abdell for his comments, that helped me to reach the solution.

I set up Tomcat heap size(memory pool size) into `512MB` for Initial memory pool and `2048MB` for the maximum memory pool(Micro Focus support adviced me to use a miximum heap size that is between 1.5GB and 2GB), and HP Service Manager Web server seems to work fine.

I hope this will help others that gets into the same issue.